# Windows recognizes external USB HDD as internal HDD: No safe removal button

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I installed windows from external HDD. And opened windows for the first time with this external HDD. And I think because of this, windows 8 recognizes this HDD as internal.

As you see, here is USB External HDD:

[image]

But No HDD in usb safe removal tool:

[image]

How to get safe removal functionality back?

Comment: what is the cache policy? is the HDD configured as safe removal or performance? http://asset1.cbsistatic.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/05/01/Quick_removal_policy.png

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you can't eject the drive that windows is booted from.

Comment: You've misunderstood. He installed from that drive and then restarted Windows with that drive still plugged in.